# How can I show a loading screen while calling multiple APIs at once?

Tags: css, angular, typescript, http

I am using Angular version 8 to write an application that gives back to users a number of responses from different APIs.
The application is calling multiple APIs at once to get responses. I need a loading symbol that will stop for each of them once they get the response.
They all vary in time from few seconds to a minute.
How can I implements something like this?

Comment: Can just make a loading variable and set it to false upon completion. Use that loading variable as the condition to show the loader

Comment: can you share the code of yoour request please?

Answer (score 1):

Check this example I made on stackblitz: [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9yos6x?file=src%2Fapp%2Fprogress-spinner-overview-example.ts)
what I did is I setup an angular material spinner and a tag where I can put my API results, in my temple:

```
<button (click)="onFetch()" >Click me to send request</button>
<mat-spinner *ngIf="spin"></mat-spinner>
<p *ngIf="!spin">{{result}}</p>
```

the button is there just to fire the request to the API.
as you can see in the template I set up an ngIf on my spinner and on my result tag, to either show the spinner or the result.
after that I make a request by clicking the button, as soon as the button is clicked, `onFetch` function is executed which make the spinner visible because of `this.spin = true`.

```
  onFetch() {
    this.spin = true
    ajax.getJSON(this.url)
    .pipe(
      delay(1000)
    )
    .subscribe(json => {
      this.spin = false
      this.result = json.value
    })
  }
```

as soon as the request returns a result, `this.spin = false` is executed and the spinner is not visible anymore.